# How do i store an object with @replit/database

Tags: node.js

I tried to store an `object` with [`@replit/database`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@replit/database):

```js
await client.set("hello", {
  something: true,
});
```

And when i log it out

```js
const hello = await client.get("hello");
console.log(hello.something);
```

`The console`:

```js
undefined
```

Maybe there is a way to do that but i don't know. If you can help, please answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned in the documentation:

> await Client.set("key", "value");

You need to pass a `key`, `value` pair, but you put an `object` as the value which causes the issue.

**Note:** if you want to store an object as a string, you can simply do this:

```
const myData = {
  something: true,
}

const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(myData)
```

Now, you need to parse the `stringifiedData` in the `get` method:

```
const testData = await client.get("test");

const myData = JSON.parse(testData)
```

Comment: can you please add the JSON output @vietanh266?

Comment: When the key got parse to an object it gives a JSON error. The codes in my answer. Also thank's for helping.

Comment: your answer was removed before i can see it, I asked you to add the get result method without parsing it @vietanh266

Comment: also for more information about parsing and stringifying, take a look at these two pages: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp and this one   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp @vietanh266